# Extendable Array-Creation Functions

Tags: arrays, matlab

According to TMW MATLAB now allows for overloading the array creation function, such as zeros ([Mathworks documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-support-for-array-creation-functions.html#bt702nr)). For example

```
zeros(n,m, 'MyClass')
```

will call

```
MyClass.zeros(n,m);
```

Since what version is this supported in Matlab? The documentation does not say it.

Comment: According to the [release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) (see Language and Programming section) this appeared in R2014a.

Comment: @horchler, I see. Thanks for the link.